# Как при нажатии на RecyclerView перейти на другой активити?

Tags: recyclerview

Я пытаюсь написать фитнес приложение для просмотра упражнений на группы мышц, но не могу реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на RecyclerView переходило на новое активити. Прошу помочь.

Это MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerview;

String muscul[];
int images[] = {R.drawable.biceps, R.drawable.chest, R.drawable.calf, R.drawable.legs, R.drawable.shoulders, R.drawable.press, R.drawable.back, R.drawable.triceps};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    muscul = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MuscleGroups);


    recyclerview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter1(this, muscul, images));
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

}

Это MyAdapter1.java

```
public class MyAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter1.MyViewHolder> {



String data1[];
int images[];
Context context;

public MyAdapter1(Context ct, String muscul[], int img[]) {
    context = ct;
    data1 = muscul;
    images = img;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.musculs.setText(data1[position]);
    holder.musculImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.length;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView musculs;
    ImageView musculImage;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        musculs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.musculs);
        musculImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.musculImage);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

прям в разметке добавь `android:onClick="open_new"`, а в коде сделай функцию `public void open_new(View view) {}` в которой открывай новую активити